# Art intuitive-random pattern recognition -from art to LLM

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have a big data set of intuitive paintings with lots of random shape recognition that I have done by myself. How can LLM use it to explore it further for more pattern recognitions?

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Could you give some more details and maybe an example of what "good" output might look like? Use [edit] to add details to the original question

Comment: I'm trying to test and see whether LLMs can benefit from intuitive pattern recognition learning. It's just another potential way of visualising images (intuitive predictions/visualisations)- for estimated/predicitve work. LLM would "search" existing patterns to extract the meaning, with "ready-filled stencils." Use may be in eg. medicine-to see changes/protein folding etc before these actually fully take place. Sorry for the limited space-I may have another go to try to be clearer. I think it's worth a try.ps. Teaching LLM intuitive pattern recogn. for many reasons-hence art very suitable..